# Designing layouts for phones and tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, tablet

I have a big confusion when designing an app for tabs. For phones of course, I know that there are five drawable folders (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi) and one layout folder.

How should it be for tabs?

Currently I am have designed for 10 inch tablets, I have three folders for drawables for 10 inch:

- drawable-sw720dp
- drawable-sw720dp-land
- drawable-sw720dp-port

And two layout folders for 10 inch tablets:

- layout-sw720dp
- layout-sw720dp-land

I am aware that when designing layout for 7 Inch tabs I need to have sw600dp folder structure just like the 10 inch tab. At the moment, I am designing all layouts one by one, for 10 inch port and land, 7 inch port and land.

My question is, can layout designing for tablets be done using one folder (like for phones) or do I always have to design for 7 inch and 10 inch tablets separately like I currently do?

Below is an image of my res folder structure:

[image]

Comment: check this blog http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Comment: and check this app http://code.google.com/p/iosched/ . The app supports devices running Android 2.3.3+, and is optimized for phones and tablets of all shapes and sizes.

Comment: thanks, how can I get the res folder structure of that app? I read the blog link that you provided. It is basically saying that we need to design for 10 and 7 inch tabs.

Comment: check the second comment download the code and look at the res/layout folder. in fact run the app and see for yourself